# How to load the JTable faster?

Tags: java, performance, swing, jtable

I have created 2 JTable in my class,

for the first JTable the data comes from server to arraylist and then to JTable

for the second JTable the data comes from local access database to JTable (no arraylist)

Both JTables will be displayed together when user click a button.

But it takes up to 1min to load and display both jtable on the interface.

Is there any way to load them faster?

Sample code Table1

```
data = new ArrayList<Person>();
try
    {
        conn = dc.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {
             String[] rowData = new String[4];
            for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
            {
                rowData[i-1] = rs.getString(i);                    
            }
            //database to arraylist
            data.add(new Person(rowData[0],rowData[1],rowData[2],rowData[3]));
        }

String[] colNames = {"LastName","FirstName","Email","Department"};
model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames,data.size())

sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    int row = 0;
    //arraylist to JTable
    for(Person p:data)
    {
        model.setValueAt(p.lastName, row, 0);
        model.setValueAt(p.firstName, row, 1);
        model.setValueAt(p.email, row, 2);
        model.setValueAt(p.dept, row, 3);
        row++;

    }
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Sample code of Table2

```
String[] colNames = {"Name","Email","Department","Status"};
model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames,500);
table.setModel(model); 

try
    {
        conn = ac.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        int row = 0;   
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String[] rowData = new String[4];
            for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
            {
                rowData[i-1] = rs.getString(i);
            }
            //access database to jTable
            model.setValueAt(rowData[0], row, 0);
            model.setValueAt(rowData[1], row, 1);
            model.setValueAt(rowData[2], row, 2);                
            model.setValueAt(rowData[3], row, 3);                
            row++;  

        }
```

Comment: no ideas without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and with detailed description about data types and sources, comments and answer will be based on infos given by yourself, long time I see miracle here last time

Comment: Could you show the code that loads the contents of the table?

Comment: unrelated: would recomment to not create the RowSorter manually, instead set the table's autoCreateRowSorter property to true - the advantage is that now the table takes care of synching the model between sorter and table (otherwise, it would be your responsibility)

Comment: i have filter option in my interface, so i need the sorter to table

Comment: are you using a jdbc/odbc connection to the access database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delay is caused by the time required to do the database queries. So you want to make sure you are doing two separate queries, each on a different thread so one query is not waiting for the other to finish.

This can be done by creating 2 SwingWorkers, one for the server access and the other for the local access.

Comment: @vijay create two instances and call execute on each ... ?

Comment: @vijay, Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Swing Workers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). Search the forum of the web for other examples.

Answer (score 2):

you can load data to jtable easily through this

```
DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
tm.addRow(new Object[] {name,age,tel});
```

name age tel are values in column1, column2, column3